# Only master can not run in zookeeper

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

Only master can not run in zookeeper-3.4.6. (ubuntu16.04)

I installed Hadoop in full distributed mode. (One master, five nodes)

All of the main keeper commands below will be executed.

```
$ ./bin/zkServer.sh start
```

However, when I use this command, it runs, but when I do not, it can not run only on the master computer.

```
$ ./bin/zkServer.sh status

zookeeper@com1:~zookeeper3.4.9$ ./bin/zkServer.sh status
zookeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Error congacting service. It is probably not running
```

What command can I use to solve this problem?

Or can I assume that the server is dead in master only and that the primary keeper installation was successful?

I saw that I had to add these commands in case of an error.

```
vi .profile
export ZK_HOME=/home/zookeeper/zookeeper/
export PATH=$PATH:$ZK_HOME/bin
```

However, I did not add this separately. Four of the five computers worked normally. Is this why the master computer does not work?

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: @MartinSerrano 
I have added an error phrase in the body. Please confirm.